# Regex matching OrgMode tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write an regex in JavaScript to match the tags in OrgMode format

Example:

- Sample title `:tag1:tag2:tag3:`

I have tested the following regex but it only matches the first and the last tags (tag1,tag3):

```
\:\w+\:
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `s.match(/(?<=:)\w+(?=:)/g)` if in Chrome or other ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environment. Or, grab Group 1 when matching with `/:(\w+)(?=:)/g` in a loop with `RegExp#exec`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/:(\w+)(?=:)/g
```

The value you need is inside Group 1. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/DKlmGM/1).

The main point is the `(?=:)` positive lookahead: it checks (and requires) but does not consume the `:` to the right of the `\w+` pattern.

See JS demo below:

```js
var s = "Sample title :tag1:tag2:tag3:";
var reg = /:(\w+)(?=:)/g;
var results = [], m;
while(m = reg.exec(s)) {
  results.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that here an expression with start and end anchors might be desired, if we'd be validating:

```
^((?=:\w+)(:\w+)+):$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/Ir2edK/1/)

```js
const regex = /^((?=:\w+)(:\w+)+):$/gm;
const str = `:tag1:tag2:tag3:
:tag1:tag2:tag3:tag4:
:tag1:tag2:tag3:tag4:tage5:
:tag1:tag2:tag3:tag4:tage5`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```